# Select line from paragraph using jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have a paragraph like:

```
some text1. some text2. some text3. some text4. some text5. some text6. some text7.
```

i want to select only 'some text2' from above paragraph onmouseover using jQuery and when i click on it the selected text should store in variable.

how to do this?

Comment: some people dont have any wrk.They spend time by playing with votes

Comment: @DavidThomas i want to select text which ends at '.'dot

Comment: And starts from where? Following the previous period, or just the last word before that period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing but from what I understand, you'd like whatever is between the full stops (and the space) to be a select-able element? How is this:

```
splitter = ". ";
$(function(){
    words = $("#text").text().split(". ");
    $("#text").html("");
    for(i=0; i< (words.length-1); i++){
        $("#text").append("<span class='textPart'>"+words[i]+"</span>"+ splitter );
    }

    $("#text").delegate(".textPart", "mouseover", function(){
        $("#hovered").html($(this).text()); 
    });
});
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MyPXy/)

Comment: Thanx @F4r-20.
this what i want it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
splitter = ". ";
$(function(){
words = $("#text").text().split(". ");
$("#text").html("");
for(i=0; i< (words.length-1); i++){
    $("#text").append("<span class='textPart'>"+words[i]+"</span>"+ splitter );
}

$("#text").delegate(".textPart", "mouseover", function(){
    $("#hovered").html($(this).text()); 
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
<p>some text1. some text2. some text3. some text4. some text5. some text6. some text7.</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('p').hover(function(){
  var s = $('p').text();
  alert(s.indexOf("some text2") !== -1);
  //true if it contains
  //false if it not ontains
   });
});
```