# Select line in paragraph using jQuery based on line break

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041833/select-line-from-paragraph-using-jquery) question may be related.

I have a Django recipe app that uses a form containing of a CharField TextArea. This field is used to enter a list of directions (string). I have chosen to separate each direction with a line break (ENTER in form), and use the following in my template (html) to keep line breaks as in original form

```
<div id="items">
    <p> 
        {{ recipe.directions_field|safe }}
    </p>
</div>
```

This will basically appear as something like

```
<div id="items">
    <p>
        Line one <br/>
        Two <br/> 
        Three <br/>
    </p>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to use jQuery to "check" (strikethrough) one single line (may contain of several words) in my template. I have tried the following, but as expected, this checks the entire paragraph.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#items p").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('stroked');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Where my css has

```
.stroked{ text-decoration: line-through; }
```

In my Django view I replaced "\n" with html line break in order to make sure line breaks are not removed when shown in template.

```
directions = directions.replace("\n", "<br/>")
```

I think a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041833/select-line-from-paragraph-using-jquery) would work if I could just find an easy way to use `<br/>` as a splitter instead of ". " or any other symbol. I couldn't make that work with `<br/>` in the example.

Any suggestions, either using a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041833/select-line-from-paragraph-using-jquery) or another way? I guess there are many ways to solve this, but hope to find an easy implementation.

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: need to wrap the text nodes in a tag like `<span>` to be able to add class to a line

Comment: can get the text nodes with javascript but easiest would be at server, then look for those spans and change class

Comment: Any other opinions considering my comment to the post below? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why can't you just split the text at line break at server and wrap ech segment?

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean. Would you post an example, please?

Comment: I mean use Django/python string methods to change the stored text to the html. One simple way would be convert string to array using line break as delimiter

Comment: Thanks again. Well, I used `directions = directions.split('<br/>')` to convert the string to an array in my view. Each line from my form is now added correctly to the variable. I still struggle when displaying this array in my template. I want to add each array element (text line) to a `<span></span>`, but how can I iterate over the array using Django template language? By doing: `{% for element in recipe.directions_field %}
<span> {{ element }} </span>
{% endfor %}`, each letter is now printed with spaces, which is not correct. I want the complete line (element in array) before linebreak.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier if you wrap every single line into `<span></span>`, like this:

```
<div id="items">
<p>
    <span>line one <br/></span>
    <span>line two <br/></span>
    <span>line three <br/></span>
</p>
</div>
```

So what you need to do in javascript is:

```
$(function(){
    $('#items > p > span').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr('class') == 'stroked'){
            $(this).removeAttr('class');
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass('stroked');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. Not sure I get how to add the spans. As I use one single form to add all lines, and use the replace function to add html line breaks, I still can't add <span> at the beginning and end of each line. This html line break replacement is done in my Django view. Maybe I can do something similar to add span at the beginning of each line and then replace "\n" by `<br/></span>`?